# C# Mysql Update last row in table

Tags: c#, mysql, row

I am trying  to update the last row inside a Mysql table. This is what I've been trying so far, but the problem is that it updates every row and not only the last one.

```
 query = "UPDATE Callbacks SET UniqueID = ?UID WHERE UniqueID = (SELECT UniqueID Callbacks ORDER BY UniqueID LIMIT 1);";
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, cn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?UID", UID));
                    cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: _the last row inside a Mysql table_ The is no such thing as a 'last', 'first' etc row in a database table. Per definition sql tables have no order in their rows. (Nor btw in their columns.) - Any order you need must be created by you by adding an  ORDER clause

Answer (score 1):

You have to use he order by in an descending order

```
UPDATE Callbacks SET UniqueID = ?UID WHERE UniqueID = (SELECT UniqueID Callbacks ORDER BY UniqueID DESC LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: That gives still changes every row

Comment: Can you provide a print of your table? Or just a small part of it?

Comment: Seems like the solution above didnt work after all, the column can look like this:
UniqueID
   3
   4
   1
   35
each number represents a row

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE Callbacks SET UniqueID = ?UID ORDER BY UniqueID DESC LIMIT 1
```

In MySQL 4.0 and later, you can use UPDATE with ORDER BY and LIMIT in the same statement. This should give you the result you are looking for. Note: I changed the ORDER BY to be descending (an assumption on my part for what you might be looking to do).

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark it as the solution :)